# Telerik RadGridview (Winform) - How To Add Combobox

Tags: c#, vb.net, telerik, telerik-grid

While I am learning Telerik Radgridview control, I am stuck with combo box column example. I have created the grid and columns using GUI property builder. It's not bound to any database. I just want to display a simple drop-down list.  For example:- {Yes, No, Maybe}

***My Question***

1. How to assign the drop-down list Item?  {Yes, No, Maybe}
2. Is it possible to assign different values to each combo box cell per row

   For Example:- row(0)= {Yes, No, Maybe}, row(1)={Absoluitely, Definately, Certain}

***Technical Info***

Gridview Name: radGridView1

Combobox Column Name: status

Application Type: VB.net WinForm

---

***Update***
Solution For the First Question
 1. How to assign the drop-down list Item?  {Yes, No, Maybe}

```
Dim comboItems() As String = {"Yes", "No", "Maybe"}  
CType(radGridView1.Columns("status"), GridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = comboItems
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: can you show us your code

Comment: I have not figure it out anything. I can show you the snippest for the textbox control, but I think its not significan. I know how to do this with MS gridview, but unfortunately I cant find any info how to assign the value to a existing combobox control in telerik rad gridview

Comment: can you show your code on how your generating your grid \ table too

Comment: as I already mentioned, I design the grid using telerik GUI property builder.